# Bootstrap 3 Modal & Dropdown Not Working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-modal

I'm new to coding with Bootstrap 3, I've been developing the homepage below, however my Dropdown menu in the navbar and my modals on the homepage have stopped working.

My other page also has a modal which does work, so I'm not sure as to what the difference is.

Can anyone help?

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Spark Media Arts</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>

        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Spark Media Arts</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">PORTFOLIO<b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Graphic Design</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Video Production</a></li>
                            </ul></li>
                <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="modal">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="jumbotron text-center">
                <h1>Spark Media Arts</h1>
                <p>"Inspiring Creativity through Media ..."</p>
                <a href="#book_workshop" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" role="button">Book A Workshop</a>
                <a href="#hire_us" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" role="button">How To Hire Us</a>
            </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <a href="gdshowreel.html" class="thumbnail home-thumb"><img src="img/thumbs/gdshow.jpg" alt="Graphic Design Showreel"></a>
                <h3>Graphic Design Showreel</h3>
                <p>Year of production: 2014<br>
                Running Time: 1:35 min<br>
                Produced for: Spark Media Arts<br>

                <br>Over the course of our first year, we've had the opportunity to produce artwork for various and some of their work and events.</p>
                <a href="gdshowreel.html" class="btn btn-danger">Read More</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail home-thumb"><img src="img/thumbs/vpshow.jpg" alt="Video Production Showreel"></a>
                <h3>Video Production Showreel</h3>
                <p>Year of production: 2014<br>
                Running Time: 3:09 min<br>
                Produced for: Spark Media Arts<br>

                <br>Over the course of our first year, we've had the opportunity to produce videos for various and some of their work and events.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Read More</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail home-thumb"><img src="img/thumbs/sppromo.jpg" alt="SP Project Promo 2014"></a>
                <h3>SP Project Promo 2014</h3>
                <p>Year of production: 2014<br>
                Running Time: 2:37 min<br>
                Produced for: SP Project<br>

                <br>Promotional Video for SP Project, an organisation working across the North East region in the UK.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal">Read More</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        </div>

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-text pull-left">
                    <p>&copy; 2014 Spark Media Arts.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-text pull-right">
                    <p>Get in touch:
                    <a href="mailto:sparkmediaarts@gmail.com" target="_blank"><img src="img/social_icons/email.png"></a>
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sparkmediaarts" target="_blank"><img src="img/social_icons/facebook.png"></a>
                    <a href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/b/106211922046524978613/106211922046524978613" target="_blank"><img src="img/social_icons/google-plus.png"></a>
                    <a href="https://www.twitter.com/sparkmediaarts" target="_blank"><img src="img/social_icons/twitter.png"></a>
                    <a href="https://www.vimeo.com/sparkmediaarts" target="_blank"><img src="img/social_icons/vimeo.png"></a>
                    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/sparkmediaarts" target="_blank"><img src="img/social_icons/youtube.png"></a>
                    </p>
                </div>
        </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->

    <div class="modal fade" id="contact" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4>Contact</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="contact-name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact-name" placeholder="First and Last Name">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="contact-email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="contact-email" placeholder="example@domain.com">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="contact-message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="book_workshop" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4>Book A Workshop</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Text coming soon!</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="hire_us" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4>How To Hire Us</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Text coming soon!</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="hire_us" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4>How To Hire Us</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Text coming soon!</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="hire_us" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4>How To Hire Us</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Text coming soon!</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    --
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try adding a closing tag for '<textarea class="form-control" rows="4"></textarea>'